# I am looking for a shorter function to group similar datasets from a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have scattered databases in a list. I would like to group databases of the same year;

```
mydata12<-data.frame(Age=c(12,13),Sex=c("F","H"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2012))
mydata13<-data.frame(Age=c(14,15),Sex=c("F","H"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2013))
mydata14<-data.frame(Age=c(16,17),Sex=c("F","H"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2014))
mydata2012<-data.frame(Age=c(18,19),Sex=c("F","H"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2012))
mydata2013<-data.frame(Age=c(20,13),Sex=c("H","H"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2013))
mydata2014<-data.frame(Age=c(22,13),Sex=c("F","F"), Weight=c(70,75),year=c(2014))



 mydatalist<-list(

  `12`=mydata12,
  `13`=mydata13,
  `14`=mydata14,
  `2013`=mydata2012,
  `2014`=mydata2013,
  `2015`=mydata2014
)
```

I can do it with this function

```
list(`2012`=rbind(mydatalist$`12`,mydata2012),
     `2013`=rbind(mydatalist$`13`,mydata2013),
     `2014`=rbind(mydatalist$`14`,mydata2014))
```

but I would like to make it shorter (without a line of code for each year), since we already have patterns `2012:2021`,

```
12:21
```

Comment: In the `mydatalist` created, is there any typos i.e. you showed `2013 = mydata2012`,  should that be `2012 = mydata2012` and for 2013 and 2014 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, use either the substring of the list names i.e. the last 2 digits or add `20` as prefix to those have only 2 characters in the list name, then `split` the `list` and `rbind`

```
out <- lapply(split(mydatalist, sub("^(\\d{2})$", "20\\1", 
  names(mydatalist))), \(x) `row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, x), NULL))
```

-output

```
> out
$`2012`
  Age Sex Weight year
1  12   F     70 2012
2  13   H     75 2012
3  18   F     70 2012
4  19   H     75 2012

$`2013`
  Age Sex Weight year
1  14   F     70 2013
2  15   H     75 2013
3  20   H     70 2013
4  13   H     75 2013

$`2014`
  Age Sex Weight year
1  16   F     70 2014
2  17   H     75 2014
3  22   F     70 2014
4  13   F     75 2014
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `bind_rows` with `group_split`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(mydatalist) %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$year))
```

```
$`2012`
  Age Sex Weight year
1  12   F     70 2012
2  13   H     75 2012
7  18   F     70 2012
8  19   H     75 2012

$`2013`
   Age Sex Weight year
3   14   F     70 2013
4   15   H     75 2013
9   20   H     70 2013
10  13   H     75 2013

$`2014`
   Age Sex Weight year
5   16   F     70 2014
6   17   H     75 2014
11  22   F     70 2014
12  13   F     75 2014
```

Comment: Thank you, this could be very helpful for some of my list of dataframe. But not all, cause I have other list of dataframe not containing  the column year. So I can join them only by name of dataframe not by column name

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how "short" you are happy with, but below might be an option

```
> split(`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, mydatalist), NULL), ~year)
$`2012`
  Age Sex Weight year
1  12   F     70 2012
2  13   H     75 2012
7  18   F     70 2012
8  19   H     75 2012

$`2013`
   Age Sex Weight year
3   14   F     70 2013
4   15   H     75 2013
9   20   H     70 2013
10  13   H     75 2013

$`2014`
   Age Sex Weight year
5   16   F     70 2014
6   17   H     75 2014
11  22   F     70 2014
12  13   F     75 2014
```